# Game with 4 coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

Consider the following game. We have 4 fair coins, they are tossed and you have 2 options, either take the amount of money equal to the number of heads that fell, or toss 4 coins again, after you toss 4 coins again you must take the money and the game ends. Obviously, the optimal strategy is: If on the first throw there are 2, 3 or 4 heads, then we take the money, but if the number of heads is 0 or 1, then we throw the coins again. How to calculate the expected value of this strategy?

I don't understand how to calculate expectations in such games, if anybody could explain on this example, I would appreciate that!

Comment: You have an explicit strategy, so just compute.  What is the probability of getting $0,1,2,3,4$ heads on the first round?  If you go to the second round then, of course, you expect to get paid $2$, so it's really only the first round you need to compute for.

Comment: It is not obvious what you do with $2$ heads from $4$, but it may not affect the expectation, so let's adopt your strategy.  You want the probabilities of $4$ on first roll, $3$ on first roll, $2$ on first roll, $1$ on first roll and $4$ on second (which counts as $4$), $1$ on first roll and $3$ on second (which counts as $3$), ...,  $0$ on first roll and $0$ on second (which counts as $0$). Then you can find the expectation from the probabilities of the various outcomes

Comment: @Henry Could you describe this as an answer in a little more detail?

Comment: @lulu I understand but that is the problem, what do we need to calculate? Could you describe in more details, I really want to understand how to deal with such problems

Comment: I said exactly what to compute, or at least how to start.  Get those $5$ values first.  Then think about what your strategy says for each outcome.

Comment: @lulu $P(H = 0) = 1/16, P(H = 1) = 4/16, P(H = 2) = 6/16, P(H = 3) = 4/16, P(H=4) = 1/16$. So the $EV = 1/2 * something + 1/2 * 2$, as understand you correctly. What gonna be instead of "somethig"?

Comment: So, you have five outcomes for the first round and their probabilities.  Now, following your strategy, what happens in each case?  To start, if you get $H=0$ then of course you re-roll, in which case you expect to get $2$.  So that's a case that expects to yield $2$.  Also of course, if you get $H=4$ initially you do not reroll so in that case you get $4$.  Analyze the other three cases similarly.

Comment: If you find it clearer you can write out all $5\times 5=25$ possible outcomes for the two rolls.  Then write out the probability of each and use your strategy to see the payout of each.  Personally, I find it easier to remark that the second round has an expected yield of $2$ and not bother with the specific cases.

Comment: @lulu following this logic, for $H = 0, 1$ i wll get 2 and for $H=2, 3, 4$ i will get 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Exactly so.  Well, with the proviso that you should write "expect to get".  In those cases where you reroll the outcome is not certain, we are just replacing it with its expected return of $2$.

Comment: @lulu Of course i could write all of the 25 possible outcomes, but that will not help me to understand some general ideas

Comment: It's always good to have the explicit list to fall back on.  If nothing else, you can definitely get the answer that way and you can use it to check whatever else you do.

Comment: @lulu got it, but i want to understand how to approach this problem without writing all of the combinations

Comment: @lulu So, I understand the point about cases when we have $H=0, 1, 2$ and expect to get 2 for the second roll. What's next?

Comment: You are done!  Well, essentially.  There are only $3$ expected outcomes ($2,3,4$) and you can read off the probabilities of each.  So just use the definition of expectation to finish.

Comment: Specifically $E=2\times (P(0)+P(1)+P(2))+3\times P(3)+4\times P(4)$.

Comment: @lulu got it! $38/16$ is the answer.

Comment: @lulu Usually this is not asked here, but i would like to get in touch to analyze similar problems, if is it possible? If this is not possible, then no problem

Comment: Not possible, sorry.  Good luck!

Comment: @lulu okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected payoff on the first round is the expectation of a Binomial distribution with parameters $(4,\frac 12)$, i.e., it is $2$. The strategy is to toss again only if the initial number of heads is less than $2$.

Let $N_1$ (resp., $N_2$) be a random variable that models the number of heads on the first (resp., second) round. $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent, and each has distribution $B(4,\frac 12)$.

The total payoff is $N_1 1_{N_1\geq 2} + N_21_{N_1\leq 1}$, and the expected payoff is $$E[N_1 1_{N_1\geq 2}] + E[N_2]
P(N_1\leq 1) = \frac {19}8 = 2.375.$$

Comment: could provide calculations of $E(N_1|N_1>1)$?

Comment: @wxist $E[N_1 1_{N_1\geq 2}] = \sum_{k=0}^4 k 1_{k \geq 2} \binom 4k \frac 1{2^4} = \sum_{k=2}^4 k  \binom 4k \frac 1{2^4}$.

Comment: could you explain why the expected payoff is $E(N_1 1_{N_1 \geq 2}) + E(N_2)P(N_1\leq 1)$, shouldn't it be equal $E(N_1|N_1\geq 2) P(N_1 \geq 2) + E(N_2|N_1\leq1)P(N_1\leq 1)$. And how to calculate $E(N_2|N_1\leq 1)$

Comment: @wxist By linearity of expectation, we look for $E[N_1 1_{N_1\geq 2}] + E[N_21_{N_1\leq 1}]$. Since $N_2$ and $N_1$ are independent, $N_2$ and $1_{N_1\leq 1}$ are also independent, thus $E[N_21_{N_1\leq 1}] = E[N_2]E[1_{N_1\leq 1}] = E[N_2]P(N_1\leq 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Find the probability of each outcome. That is to say, find the probability we get 0 heads and toss again and get 0 heads, we get 0 heads, toss again and get 1 heads, etc. for every possible outcome. You can do this in a table or figure out if there's a nice expression. You can make this faster by finding the probabilities for 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 heads in the first round and then multiplying these probabilities by the probability of 0 and 1 for the games that advance to the second round, according to your strategy. All together you should have 13 possible outcomes (I noticed in a comment you said you have 25. This is not true).

Then multiply the amount of money you get for each outcome by the outcome itself e.g. the probability of getting 4 heads the first round and stopping is $1/16$ and you get $4$ "monies" for this outcome so our product is $\frac{4}{16}=0.25$. Once you've done this for each outcome, add them all up and this is your expected value.

This comes from the formula $E[X]=\sum_x xp(x)$ where $x$ is the value of the outcome and $p(x)$ is the probability of said outcome.

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut here is to notice that if you always decided to take the second throw, your expected win would be $2$, since this is the expected result of the second throw. But if you throw three heads in the first round, you instead win $3$, gaining $1$. And if you throw four heads in the first round, you win $4$, gaining $2$. Therefore the expectation is $2+p_3+2p_4$, where $p_i$ is the probability of throwing $i$ heads in the first round.